# Can you use a swift action and an immediate action on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

> Using an immediate action on your turn is the same as using a swift
>   action, and counts as your swift action for that turn. You cannot use
>   another immediate action or a swift action until after your next turn
>   if you have used an immediate action when it is not currently your
>   turn (effectively, using an immediate action before your turn is
>   equivalent to using your swift action for the coming turn). You also
>   cannot use an immediate action if you are flat-footed.

Based on this, can I take a standard action, a swift action, and an immediate action (consuming the next turn's swift action) all on the same turn?

For example:

1. Swift Action: Cast Inspirational Boost
2. Immediate Action: Activate Badge of Valor
3. Standard Action: Activate Inspire Courage

I don't believe this can be done, but I could be mistaken. Please let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106325/8610)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical creature that on its turn takes a swift action can't also on its turn take a immediate action and *vice versa*. A creature that takes on its turn *either* an immediate action *or* a swift action, however, can, after its turn ends, take an immediate action *before* the creature's next turn, but doing so costs the creature its swift action for its upcoming turn.

The 1st-level bard spell ***inspirational boost*** [ench] (*Spell Compendium* 124) says, "While this spell is in effect, the morale bonus granted by your inspire courage bardic music increases by 1," but then says, "If you don’t begin to use your inspire courage ability before the beginning of your next turn, the spell’s effect ends." To get the spell's benefits, it's mandatory to cast the spell *before* starting the bardic music effect inspire courage.

However, the ***badge of valor*** (*Magic Item Compendium* 208) (1,400 gp; 0 lbs.) says, in part, "If you have the bardic music ability to inspire courage, you can activate a *badge of valor* to increase the bonus granted by that ability by 1 for the duration of its effect." This means that the *badge* must be activated *after* an inspire courage effect has already been started, and, as activating the badge is an immediate action, that can be done off-turn during the initiative count right after the bard's turn.

Thus on the bard's turn she can take a swift action to cast the spell *inspirational boost* then take a standard action to start the inspire courage effect. After her turn ends, she can then take an immediate action to activate the *badge of valor*, foregoing her upcoming turn's swift action. In combination, this applies to the inspire courage effect *both* the spell's benefit *and* the item's benefit.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot. An immediate action used on your turn uses that turn’s swift action. Can’t do it if you've already used that, and doing it prevents any other swift action that turn.

You can, however, use your actions in your turn, including the swift, and then allow your turn to end before using the immediate action. Then the immediate action counts against the next turn’s swift. This does potentially mean losing benefits of things that only work on your turn or last until the end of your turn, so it’s not precisely the same as you describe, but it’s pretty close.